# Should old mineral felt be removed from a roof before applying new felt?

Tags: roof, shed

I will soon have to re-felt a shed roof, almost flat, not pitched. As in nearly horizontal. Are there any advantages/disadvantages in leaving the old felt in place, or should that definitely come off first?

Seems to me leaving it on is 'belt and braces', but there may be some good reason for it to be removed and replaced.

Comment: @isherwood - this felt is roofing felt, made for shed roofs. Green stuff. Not the underfelt one uses before fitting tiles (on a nearly flat/horizontal roof..?)

Comment: I realize now that you're talking about what I know as "mineral roofing" or "roll roofing". "Felt" is probably a legacy term, as most of it is fiberglass-based nowdays.

Comment: @isherwood - yes, quite heavy, not paper-like, comes on rolls a metre wide, and uses black tar-like gunge to join edges. Hardly needs any nails, it's so heavy. It's over 1/2" ply to stop any sagging, and can be walked on,  but I can't locate several leaks.

Comment: "Roofing felt" is still the term used in the UK. Supposedly made from modified bitumen and polyester, or sometimes fiberglass. See for instance https://www.roofingsuperstore.co.uk/help-and-advice/product-guides/flat-roofing/roofing-felt-buyers-guide FWIW that page recommends removing the existing felt before laying the new but they don't give specific reasons for it.

Comment: Having had so many issues with shoddy roofing in my life I now insist that the roofing company remove all old materials and install precisely to the spec of the product they're using. New felt is not expensive. Problems and contractors making excuses for leaks are expensive

Answer (score 0):

Two layers of felt is recommended for flat roofs. So if the old stuff is good, I would leave it

https://housinghow.com/2-layers-roofing-felt-on-shed-roof/

> The National Roofing Contractors Association [NRCA]  even suggests a double layering of roof felt underlayment.

Comment: That page refers to underlayment. That's not apparently what this question is about.

Comment: The writer seems a little confused, which has in turn confused me. And what's 15lb felt??

Comment: @Tim I think it's a US v UK thing. In the US, [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Warrior-Roofing-36-in-x-144-ft-432-sq-ft-Felt-Roof-Underlayment/3005594) is US "roofing felt". It comes in 15lb or 30lb weights (pounds per... square yard maybe?) and is used as an underlayment layer between the roof sheathing and the shingles - it's not designed for long-term exposure to weather. In the UK, it seems that "roofing felt" is a roofing material that is designed for direct weather exposure for decades.